# read a DER Application Specific (asn1-java-bouncycastle)

Tags: java, bouncycastle, der, asn.1

I'm trying to translate with a Bouncy castle asn1 libraries an object of type DER ApplicationSpecific (or maybe it's an array?) but I m not able to navigate the structure.
With the simple following code ( arr is my byte array)

```
ASN1InputStream bIn = new ASN1InputStream (new ByteArrayInputStream (
arr);
DERApplicationSpecific primitive = (DERApplicationSpecific) bIn.readObject 
();
System.out.println (ASN1Dump.dumpAsString (primitive));
```

I get this print:

```
DER ApplicationSpecific [21] (432b30363a3435223b6461796c696768742d736176696e672d74696d653d223031223b6e6574776f726b2d70726f7669646564bf1f818f313d800103813832363230333036323436323439313737343632303535)
```

I can guess that this is an array of 21 elements but I can not go deeper
Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can not go deeper Can anyone help me?

Most likely not, as name of object suggests, it is application specific.

`21` in string output means `tag` value, not number of sub elements.

You can call `getContents()` to obtain underlying byte array and `getApplicationTag()` to obtain tag value (21 in your case).

How to interpret that data, it is not known without more details.